# DataTables Horizontal Line Below thead

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I would like to define a horizontal line below the titles within DataTables (below thead und before tbody).

When I give the thead a border-bottom of 1px it disappears after completing the load of DataTables:

```
<thead>                 
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
    <td>CONTENT</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

How do I get this horizontal line below the thead?

Comment: I think you can add <hr/> in the html

Comment: If your border is dissappearing it could be that the overflow is hidden automatically. Try and add box-sizing: border-box; to ensure it's within 'the div'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try this.
add this line after datatable load function

```
$("thead tr").css("border-bottom","5px solid #000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically HTML table structure uses the `th` element (instead of `td`) to denote column headings.  So in a structure like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You could simply target the header cells with the border you want:

```
th{
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```